# Generic xml data together with xml (de)serialization?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am making a program that will load up a configuration file (not app.config though) that is xml-based.

In this configuration file I will specify types that must be instantiated by the program, and configured.

Here's an example of how I envision this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <types>
        <type assembly="SomeAssembly.dll" class="SomeAssembly.SomeClass">
            <type-configuration>
               <address>192.168.0.1</address>
               <port>80</port>
            </type-configuration>
        </type>
    </types>
</configuration>
```

That innermost element is the problem, `<type-configuration>`. The elements inside there will depend on the specific configuration needed by `SomeAssembly.SomeClass`, and not be "known" to the program at all.

By adding a new type, that part might look like this:

```
<type assembly="SomeAssembly.dll" class="SomeAssembly.SomeClass">
    <type-configuration>
       <address>192.168.0.1</address>
       <port>80</port>
    </type-configuration>
</type>
<type assembly="SomeOtherAssembly.dll" class="SomeOtherAssembly.SomeOtherClass">
    <type-configuration>
       <url>http://www.domain.com/path/to/webpage</url>
       <authentication-token>1234567890ABC</authentication-token>
    </type-configuration>
</type>
```

Is there any way I can deserialize the above XML file into strongly typed objects, and still carry that sub-XML portion with me, so that the type itself can deserialize that into its own objects?

ie. the configuration class of my program could be something like this:

```
[XmlType("configuration")]
public class Configuration
{
    [XmlElement("types")]
    public Collection<SubType> Types
    {
        ...
    }
}

[XmlType("type")]
public class SubType
{
    [XmlElement("configuration")]
    public ??? Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

How do I declare that `SubType.Configuration` property? Is that even possible?

Note that eventually, whatever data is in that property will be given to the instantiated object of the type specified in the configuration file. I have not yet written that part, so whatever would work would be fine really,

Here is a complete [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates what I want, and how far I've gotten:

```
void Main()
{
    const string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<configuration>
    <types>
        <type assembly=""SomeAssembly.dll"" class=""SomeAssembly.SomeClass"">
            <type-configuration>
            <address>192.168.0.1</address>
            <port>80</port>
            </type-configuration>
        </type>
        <type assembly=""SomeOtherAssembly.dll"" class=""SomeOtherAssembly.SomeOtherClass"">
            <type-configuration>
            <url>http://www.domain.com/path/to/webpage</url>
            <authentication-token>1234567890ABC</authentication-token>
            </type-configuration>
        </type>
    </types>
</configuration>";

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Configuration));
    using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        var configuration = (Configuration)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        configuration.Dump();
    }
}

[XmlType("configuration")]
public class Configuration
{
    private readonly Collection<SubType> _Types = new Collection<SubType>();

    [XmlArray("types")]
    public Collection<SubType> Types
    {
        get
        {
            return _Types;
        }
    }
}

[XmlType("type")]
public class SubType
{
    private readonly Collection<XmlNode> _Configuration = new Collection<XmlNode>();

    [XmlAttribute("assembly")]
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("class")]
    public string ClassName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("type-configuration")]
    public Collection<XmlNode> Configuration
    {
        get
        {
            return _Configuration;
        }
    }
}
```

This will dump out the two `SubType` objects, but the `Configuration` property only contains the first sub-element of the `<type-configuration>...</type-configuration>` part. Changing the property type to `string` only gives me the innermost text, ie. the ip address or the url, and changing it to `XmlDocument` gives me the same as for `XmlNode`.

Comment: I am unable to come up with the right keywords to plunk into Google, so if I used the wrong tags, and/or title, and/or terminology in the above question, feel free to edit in the right things.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Linq2Xml to parse your xml, instead of trying to deserialize with XmlSerializer

```
var types = XDocument.Parse(xml)
                .Descendants("type")
                .Select(t => new SubType
                {
                    AssemblyName = t.Attribute("assembly").Value,
                    ClassName = t.Attribute("class").Value,
                    Configuration = t.Element("type-configuration")
                                     .Elements()
                                     .ToDictionary(c=>c.Name.LocalName,c=>c.Value)
                })
                .ToList();
```

---

```
public class SubType
{
    public string AssemblyName { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Configuration { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: There's about 45 different types that will (potentially) be serialized from this file, I don't want to write custom code to handle all the properties for each one.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I don't understand. I didn't use anything depending on the *configuration* like *url* or *port* in the code. Only the common attributes of type